# Will the lifetime of a temporary created in the argument list to a function taking a *non*-const reference parameter encompass the function call?

Tags: c++, reference

I have become accustomed to the fact that a **const** reference extends the lifetime of a temporary until the reference goes out of scope:

```
class X {};

{
    X const & x = X();

    // Lifetime of x extended to the end of the scope
    // in which x is declared because it was declared
    // as a *const* reference
}
```

... And I am also aware that a **temporary** lives until the end of the *expression* in which it is created:

```
// Contrived example to make a point about lifetime of a temporary in an expression

class Y
{
public:
    Y() : y(5) {}
    Y & operator+=(int const & rhs)
    {
        y += rhs;
        return *this;
    }
    int foo() { return y; }
private:
    int y;
};

// n in the following line of code is 11 and the code is valid
// - the lifetime of the temporary persists to the end of the expression

int n = (Y() += 6).foo();
```

Assuming I am correct about both of the above, I suspect that it is true that a temporary created in a function argument list will persist for the lifetime of the function call even if it is bound to a **non**-const reference:

```
class X {};
void foo(X & x)
{
    // x is valid in this function,
    // even though the parameter is declared
    // as a *non*-const reference - correct?
}

// Valid, I think, even though the function parameter
// is declared as a **non**-const reference
// - because the lifetime of the temporary persists until the expression
// is fully evaluated - right?

foo(X());
```

I imagine that my experience and understanding is correct - that it is safe to bind the temporary created in the function argument list to the **non**-const reference parameter.

But I'd like to confirm I am right about this, because I was not able to find this question *explicity* answered anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: References to non-const don't bind to temporaries. Your question is moot.

Comment: @jrok: they do when using MSVC.

Comment: `+` is a really bad name for `+=`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I guess it is safe to assume an implicit "in standard C++" here.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Ok. But they're not supposed to :)

Comment: Aah - That explains it.  I *am* using MSVC... I wanted to confirm this behavior, and apparently it is a good thing I did, because now I understand that it is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you are right.

The standard:

> ### 12.2 Temporary objects [class.temporary]

[...]

> There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the fullexpression.
> The first context is when a default constructor is called to initialize an element of an array. If
> the constructor has one or more default arguments, the destruction of every temporary created in a default
> argument is sequenced before the construction of the next array element, if any.
> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference except:
> — A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits.
> — A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.
> — The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.
> — A temporary bound to a reference in a new-initializer (5.3.4) persists until the completion of the
> full-expression containing the new-initializer.

Want to ask the question again using one more level of constructors, and objects storing references?

Comment: Odd, it doesn't say anything about `const`.  I thought that `const` was typically required on the declaration of a reference to extend the lifetime of a temporary.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Automatic/static `const` references extend the lifetime beyond the full statement, here it's about the standard lifetime.

Comment: `The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference` (from the quote in the answer) reads, to me, to mean that the lifetime of the temporary is extended beyond the full expression in which the temporary is declared.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Never forget the list of exceptions.

Comment: The simple case (not in my question) of `X & x = X();` seems not to be an exception, but it does not say `const` is required, something I thought *was* required.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum I think MSVC accepts that as a non-standard exception. $0.02

Answer (score 2):

Deduplicator has given the language lawyer answer, here is the implementation detail answer:

If you pass any object by reference, you are effectively passing a pointer to that object. Since the caller is only passing a pointer to the object, the object that is passed by reference *must be constructed by the caller*.

The callee, on the other hand, only ever sees the pointer that is passed in. It does not see *how* the caller has constructed the object whose pointer is passed. This object could be a temporary (only in the case of a `const` reference, because temporaries cannot be passed as non-const references), or a variable with function scope, it could be an object that was already passed to the caller by its caller, it could even be an object allocated with `new`. As such, it cannot destruct the object because it does not know how.

Consequently, it is up to the caller to clean up the temporary *after the callee returns control to the caller* - anything that is passed in by reference must live for the entire runtime of the callee.

Note that this entire argument is completely ignorant as to whether the reference is `const` or not.

Comment: Now I'm confused, because in your answer you say it's *legal* (and that makes sense to me), but in the comments beneath the question, @jrok and others say it is *illegal*.  What am I missing?

Comment: Actually, I never thought about whether it is legal to pass a temporary as a non-const reference when phrasing my answer. Of course, the commentators are right that a temporary cannot be passed as a non-const reference. But that only takes one of the possible call scenarios out, it does not have any impact on the argument itself. I will try to clarify things a bit.